# failed run Postgres in alpine dockerfile

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, command-line, centos

i am trying to deploy my Go app with Alpine in docker, I was able to use it on my Mac and then going to Production with Centos 8 got issues
here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc && apk add --no-cache libc-dev && apk add --no-cache --update make

# Set the current working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. they will be cached of the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the WORKDIR inisde the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build .

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid

// this commands below like "psql -c ;'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS prod'"
// "psql -c ;'CREATE USER prod'"
RUN make setup

# Exporse port 3000 or 8000 to the outisde world
EXPOSE 3000..

CMD ["make", "run" ]
```

then i got error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

on my `make setup` i do the migration, create user, database

can make SUPERUSER on psql for that alpine also??

what u can see on the above syntax, is there any wrong and how to correct it? I have stuck from yesterday

Comment: Please post `some syntax here......` parts here. removing your passwords, IPs.

Comment: just updated @SachithMuhandiram

Answer (score 0):

Delete your original docker file's from 8th line to 20th and add these.

If your folder structure like this :

```
- directory
    |
    -> Dockerfile
    -> go.mod
    -> go.sum
    -> go source files
```

```
# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY . /app

# Set the current working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

RUN go mod download

RUN go build .
```

Comment: got erro when on COPY command: `When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /`

Comment: @certual error gave you the answer too... `COPY go.mod go.sum /app/`, I also updated answer.

Comment: got error again : `can't load package: package .: no Go files in /app`

Comment: when i run `RUN ls` my files not there, only go.mod and go.sum

Comment: @certual add  `RUN ls` after `WORKDIR /app` line and check whether files are there.

Comment: when i run RUN ls my files not there, only go.mod and go.sum

Comment: when i change to `COPY . . /app/` files were there , and after it downlaoded and on run `make setup`, i got error like above `psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: i follow your edited answered before and it was same issue like above ,

Comment: seems to be a problem with postgreql. Are you sure postgresql is running inside docker image?

Comment: @certual sorry mate, I dont know about postgresql. But seems it a problem with psql than docker. Initially I thought you have missed some files.

Comment: should i insyall postgres container for this ?? i didnt install it on container ? just use it on docker golang:alpine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215212/discussion-between-sachith-muhandiram-and-certual).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run database commands in a Dockerfile.

By analogy, consider the `go generate` command: you can embed special comments in your Go source code that ask the Go compiler to run programs for you, typically to generate other source files.  Say you `//go:generate: psql ...` in your source code and run `go generate ... && go install .`  Now you run that compiled binary on a different system.  Since you're not pointing at the same database any more, the database setup is lost.

In the same way, a Dockerfile produces a compiled artifact (in this case the Docker image) and it needs to run independently of its host environment.  In your example you could `docker push` the image you built on MacOS to a registry, and `docker run` it from the CentOS host without rebuilding it (and that's probably better practice for a production system).

For the specific commands you show in the question, you could put them in a database container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, or otherwise just run them once pointing at your database.  For more general-purpose database setup you might look at running a database migration tool at application startup, either in your program's `main()` function or in a wrapper entrypoint script.

Comment: did you mean I should push the `image`  of `go app`  to `docker hub` and then run it on CentOS by pull that image?  on that Makefile scripts, I do a lot of run commands `psql`, did u have any example for this, i still don't get it so far :D

Comment: let say i have containers go_app and go_postgres, and then on go_app doesn't has any psql packages, could i use `//go:generate: psql ` ?

Comment: The important detail is that "building the application" and "configuring the database" are separate steps: you can build the application or Docker image once, and use the resulting artifact against several different databases.  You might need to run the manual `psql` steps out of your Makefile as part of your deployment process, separate from anything you do with Docker.

Comment: to migration, i need the generate `sql-migrate` that required go  on my app, so is that mean i should install go also on configuration database container?